# Fine-tuning Hugging Face’s Llama Model with Unlabelled Data from PDFs from niche domain

Tags: transformer, huggingface, finetuning, llm

I’m unsure about the next steps. Specifically, I have the following questions:

- How can I prepare my unlabelled data for the fine-tuning process?
- What’s the best way to fine-tune the Llama model with my specific dataset?
- Are there any specific considerations or best practices I should be aware of when fine-tuning a model with unlabelled data?

I have a large amount of raw text data scraped from thousands of PDFs in a specific domain. I want to use this unlabelled data to fine-tune the Llama model from Hugging Face’s Transformers library.

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I’ve successfully scraped the text from the PDFs and have it stored in a suitable format.

Comment: Have you found a way? I'm in the same situation. Thanks